# UITableViewController swift different sizes of height with images

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an `UITableViewController` that has 2 cells and when I put a photo in it, it comes out to be the same size. The coding I put in the **ViewController.swift** is

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var imageArray = ["1.png","2.png"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell!

        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do and what the problem is?

Comment: Im trying to get 2 cells to have different height so it all the pictures would not be big and some too small.

Comment: Check what @charlesthierry wrote as an answer. You need to use that method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you are looking for? If what you want is two cells with differents height, you should try to override

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
}
```

in your [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:).

Comment: Im trying to get 2 cells to have different height so it all the pictures would not be big and some too small.